# Dropbox function not importing or working from other local file

Tags: python, function, dropbox-api, pythonanywhere

I have two python files, one where I have written and store functions and another where they are used.

The ‘HW’ function imports and runs, however the dbxupld does not. Can anyone suggest how I could get this to work. Many thanks.

**Python_script1.py**

```
def HW():
    print('Hello, World!')


def dbxupld(FileFROM,FileTO):
    import dropbox

    class TransferData:
        def __init__(self, access_token):
            self.access_token = access_token
        def upload_file(self, file_from, file_to):
            dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(self.access_token)
            with open(file_from, 'rb') as f:
                dbx.files_upload(f.read(), file_to)

    def main():
        access_token = "[access code hidden]"
        transferData = TransferData(access_token)
        file_from = FileFROM
        file_to = FileTO
        transferData.upload_file(file_from, file_to)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

**Python_script2.py**

```
from Python_script1 import HW
from Python_script1 import dbxupld

HW()

FileFROM = '/home/Setup stuff.pdf'
FileTO = '/upload_testing/Setup Stuff.pdf'
dbxupld(FileFROM,FileTO)
```

**Out:**

```
Hello, World!
```

*But no dropbox upload*

Comment: Why are you adding  `if __name__ == '__main__':` in script1?

Comment: It doesn't work because you have `__name__=='__main__'` inside your function. That condition will not be satisfied because you're importing this module in your other script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is being imported correctly. The problem lies in this part:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Since you're importing Python_script1 inside Python_script2, the value of `__name__` inside Python_script1 is `Python_script1` and not `__main__`. The condition is not met and `main` never gets called. To make this work, remove the condition `if __name__ == 'main'`.

For more information about `__main__` and `__name__`, refer [https://docs.python.org/3/library/**main**.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Comment: Many thanks, still getting my head around class and__main__ stuff etc. I’m coming from a matlab background and still learning. Thanks